# Using foreach with SplFixedArray

Tags: php, spl

It seems like I can't iterate by reference over values in an SplFixedArray:

```
$spl = new SplFixedArray(10);
foreach ($spl as &$value)
{
    $value = "string";
}
var_dump($spl);
```

Outputs:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'An iterator cannot be used with foreach by reference'
```

Any workaround?

Comment: The way to prepopulate using a foreach loop is using the key: `foreach ($spl as $key => $value) { $spl[$key] = "string"; }`

Comment: SplFixedArray doesn't work with references at any part; it is not limited to iteration.

Answer (score 6):

> Any workaround?

Short answer: don't iterate-by-reference. This is an exception thrown by almost all of PHP's iterators (there are *very* few exceptions to this exception); it isn't anything special for `SplFixedArray`.

If you wish to re-assign values in a `foreach` loop, you can use the key just like with a normal array.  I wouldn't call it a *workaround* though, as it is the proper and expected method.

---

### Original: bad

```
$spl = new SplFixedArray(10);
foreach ($spl as &$value)
{
    $value = "string";
}
var_dump($spl);
```

### Assign by key: good

```
$spl = new SplFixedArray(10);
foreach ($spl as $key => $value)
{
    $spl[$key] = "string";
}
var_dump($spl);
```

Comment: This is correct. There is no way to iterate by reference with SplFixedArray, so the correct answer is to not do it...

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, the only advantage of splfixedarray() is that it is faster than a normal array. But I don't remember anyone referring to an array as slow. So your best solution is probably to switch to a regular array.

Comment: It's not always faster; but the biggest benefit is significantly lower memory usage (especially when working with large volumes of data) rather than performance... in fact they're significantly slower when iterating using foreach, but marginally faster when accessing directly by key

Comment: That's is interesting, thanks for the insight. However, I think that a regular array may be his only option to pass by ref. More than likely, one of the things that allows them to be faster, is that they have less features.

Comment: The key question is __why__ he needs to pass by reference... I already commented on using the key to bulk populate against the original question, but without knowing what OP really wants it's difficult to advise

Comment: This is true. Also as a heads-up, your suggestion about using `foreach` would effectively be the same as what I suggested in this answer. (as PHP would create a regular array in the process)

Comment: No, My suggestion was populating the SPLFixedArray by key, not creating a regular array.... you wouldn't be able to do `sort($spl)` or `array_walk()`, etc.

Comment: @DesmondHume - if you explained your end goal, I might be able to suggest a few other things to watch out for; SPLFixedArray is a great memory saver in the right circumstances, but there are a few things you need to watch out for; and depending on your purpose there may be other datastructures that are better suited

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm coming from the world of C++ and, using PHP native associative arrays as plain, old school collection of elements 80% of the time, it makes me cringe to guess how much they are over-implemented, perhaps with hash maps or binary linked lists, and all the overhead.

Comment: Well SPL does give you access to Stacks, Heaps, Double Linked Lists and other data structures... PHP's "hashmap" arrays are incredibly flexible and powerful, but with a big memory overhead and a non-OOP approach to everything. SPL datastructures provide a lot more efficient approach, but only when used in the right situations